# Oracle - date column in index is ignored

Tags: oracle, indexing

We have several indexes including date columns which looks in Explain Plan that aren't necessary ,

Example for table A with columns ID NUMBER and CREATE_DATE DATE columns,

There's no primary key and have index A_I1 with both columns

```
CREATE TABLE A (ID NUMBER,CREATE_DATE DATE);
CREATE INDEX A_I1 ON A (ID, CREATE_DATE);
```

When I do Explain plan on select without date column oracle still uses the index, SQL

```
 SELECT * from A where ID = 1;
```

Explain plan:

```
INDEX RANGE SCAN | A_I1
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - access("ID"=1)
```

Explain plan on select with only date column oracle still uses the index with `FULL SCAN`, SQL:

```
SELECT * from A where CREATE_DATE = sysdate;
```

Explain plan:

```
INDEX FULL SCAN | ZZ_A_I1
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - access("CREATE_DATE"=SYSDATE@!)
* 1 - filter("CREATE_DATE"=SYSDATE@!)
```

Why date column is ignored?

Comment: What to you mean by "why date column is ignored?" The filter is `where ID = 1` and you are not using the `CREATE_DATE` column in the filter; why should the `CREATE_DATE` column be involved?

Comment: What do you mean by "Why date column is ignored?"? What's the problem here?

Comment: @stickybit how it uses index without date column which is part of the index

Comment: @MT0 I expected the index to be used only if date column is part of the conditions

Comment: Why shouldn't it use it? The index is suitable to support look ups on the ID as the ID is the first part of its keys.

Comment: Why? The first column of the composite-index is the `id` column so it is going to be indexed first by `id` and second by `create_date`; why should it not use it? If you do a select filtering by just `CREATE_DATE` then it will not use the index as the `CREATE_DATE` column is second in the index so it can't filter by the index.

Comment: @MT0 So what's the meaning of adding more than one column from index if ,e.g. I can remove CREATE_DATE from index

Comment: @stickybit I thought if you make an index with more than 1 column you expected to provide in select filters/conditions over all of the relevant column to get effective results

Comment: @user7294900: In general any index that begins with all columns of a filter can be used to support the filter. Your index can support a filter by ID and date or just by ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/indexes-and-index-organized-tables.html#GUID-ABE1DE2A-59CC-4ADE-86A5-426B16459464) (emphasis added):

> Composite indexes can speed retrieval of data for `SELECT` statements in which the `WHERE` clause references all **or the leading portion of the columns** in the composite index. Therefore, the order of the columns used in the definition is important. In general, the most commonly accessed columns go first.

If you filter against only leading columns - `id` in your case - then the index is still used to identify those rows, and the other columns are ignored. If you filter against all of the columns in the index then fewer index entries will be identified; so when you do know both column values you're searching for, that will still be more efficient.

If you will only ever filter in `id` and will always retrieve all dates then there wouldn't be much point making it a composite index, but if you will sometimes/usually filter on both columns then the composite is better than indexing just on `id` (or having separate indexes for `id` and `create_date`).

If you filter just on `create_date` Oracle can sometimes choose to do a 'skip scan' if it thinks that is sensible:

> In some cases, such as when the leading column has very low cardinality, the database may use a skip scan of this index (see "[Index Skip Scan](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/indexes-and-index-organized-tables.html#GUID-BB75CC6E-90E5-457F-A4A0-0ABBEB755181)").

Even when it can't do that, it might do a full index scan, if it thinks that's more efficient than a full table scan - again partly depends on the cardinality, but also on whether you're referring to any non-indexed columns.

In your example it seems likely that `id` is unique and therefore each `id` can only have a single `create_date`, which might affect your index design - but at the moment you can potentially still use a skip scan on that index to find rows created in a certain date range.

If you real table actually has other columns then if you only want to retrieve the ID and date values, having the date in the index also means it might not need to look at the table at all - it can get everything it needs from the index, with fewer cache/disk hits. (Again, this is all subject to what the optimiser decides is the most efficient access path for the specific query, data and statistics...)

Comment: I don't see skip scan in explain plan (`SELECT * from A where CREATE_DATE = sysdate`)

Comment: @user7294900 - no, I said 'sometimes' - from a note in the same docs, 'In some cases, such as when the leading column has very low cardinality, the database may use a skip scan of this index (see "[Index Skip Scan](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/indexes-and-index-organized-tables.html#GUID-BB75CC6E-90E5-457F-A4A0-0ABBEB755181)"). That cardinality rules doesn't seem to apply to your data.

Answer (score 1):

If the column `ID` is a primary key  you will never see an `INDEX SKIP SCAN` on an index with ID as the leading column.

Why?

Oracle would have to skip each row in the index to get to the DATE column, effectively meaning you would acces each row of the table.
Oracle knows that this is much better done with the `TABLE ACCESS FULL`.

Similar is true for  a column with a *high number of distinct values*.

*Index skip scan* shine in a case when the leading index column have only few values - in the eaxmple bellow the `GROUP_ID` has only three values.
Oracle decides to use the skip scan, because it is *only three time as costly as to do the index access using index build on the DATE column* - much bettwer that FULL SCAN of a large table

**Example**

```
create table B as
select mod(rownum,3) group_id, date'1990-01-01'+rownum CREATE_DATE 
from dual connect by level <= 1000000;

CREATE INDEX B_I1 ON B (ID, CREATE_DATE);

select * from B where CREATE_DATE = DATE'1991-01-01';

Plan hash value: 1197563700

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     1 |    11 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX SKIP SCAN | B_I1 |     1 |    11 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("CREATE_DATE"=TO_DATE(' 1991-01-01 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
       filter("CREATE_DATE"=TO_DATE(' 1991-01-01 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Comment: ID isn't a primary key (stated in question)

Comment: @user7294900 sorry I re-read it, but the point is in the *high number of distinct values of the ID column*. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is able to search data in index even when not all columns are part of the query.

This is why you see RANGE SCAN - database is ready to look through a range of index entries that have ID=1 and ingnoring what is in CREATE_DATE.

Comment: So only the first key is important? if so why adding more columns to index?

Comment: Not only the first. Since 9i version Oracle is able to use every part of index if a column is specified within WHERE part. In this case you'll see "INDEX SKIP SCAN" operation

Comment: IT depends on oracle to decide which method is to be implemented on a specific step. In this case database decided it is cheaper to scan the whole index.

Perhaps if you had three or more columns indexed and looked for that one which is in the middle of definition, then the SKIP SCAN is most probable decision